# Freebase api get album by track

Tags: api, freebase

I need a Freebase **api url** to get all music album info searched by artist and composition. For example: 
Artist: Dark Tranquillity,
Composition: Uniformity. Result must contain info from page http://www.freebase.com/m/0txs58q
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you looked at any of the API documentation?

Comment: Hi. I tried this URL ```https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=Uniformity&type=/music/release_track&mql_output=[{%22mid%22:null,%22name%22:null,%22/music/release_track/release%22:null,%22/common/topic/alias%22:null}]``` I need to get exactly This URL ````http://www.freebase.com/m/0txs58q``` as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want album information, you need to ask for it, not the album releases, which are separate. Try this:

[https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=Uniformity&type=/music/release_track&mql_output=%5B%7B%22name%22%3anull,%22mid%22%3anull,%22/common/topic/alias%22%3a%5B%5D,%22/music/release_track/release%22:{%22album%22%3a%5B%7B%22mid%22%3anull,%22name%22%3anull%7D%5D%7D}%5D](https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=Uniformity&type=/music/release_track&mql_output=%5B%7B%22name%22%3anull,%22mid%22%3anull,%22/common/topic/alias%22%3a%5B%5D,%22/music/release_track/release%22%3a%7B%22album%22%3a%5B%7B%22mid%22%3anull,%22name%22%3anull%7D%5D%7D%7D%5D)

Comment: All "Construct" albums found by this query doesn't have description on their pages. Only http://www.freebase.com/m/0txs58q has description. That's why I need a query to find exactly this URL http://www.freebase.com/m/0txs58q

Comment: If you want the album instead of the release, just add that to the query.  I've edited my reply.